# How can I tell which custom UITableViewCell's UIButton has been tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a couple of UIButton's on it.

I have both IBOutlet's and IBAction's set up from the buttons to my custom TableViewCell.

Now, when I go to use this custom cell on a TableViewController, how can I know in my controller which cell's X button was tapped?

Say I have an X and Y button on every cell, and I'm using dynamic cell's. Let's say I have 10. The user clicks the X button on the 2nd cell.

My custom UITableViewCell code will fire IBAction's xButtonTapped. How do I relay that information on to my TableViewController? Delegation?

And if so, how do I know which cell the user tapped the button on?

Comment: I think the tap can be passed through to the cells super view. This means you can handle in cellforrowatindexpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a protocol on the cell, which the tableview controller will conform to, then you can call a method on button click and can even send "self" as a parameter to get the actual cell.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be to set a Tag for the button when the table is being created in the protocol, something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.youCellButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    //... whatever aditional logic you want to implement here...

    return cell;
}
```

Then from you IBAction you just check the tag of the sender and assigned to a class variable or something like that:

```
int clickedButtonCell = [sender tag]
```